# Finding multiplicative inverse modulo n using matrix method

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

According to [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=37g6lixYggs) (15:17 onwards), there is a "matrix method" to find the multiplicative inverse of $a$ mod $n$ by row reducing $$\begin{bmatrix} 
a & 1\\
n & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

In the author's case, to find $97^{-1} mod\ n$, he did row operations: 
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
97 & 1\\
224 & 0
\end{array}
\right] \sim
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
97 & 1\\
30 & -2
\end{array}
\right] \sim
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
7 & 7\\
30 & -2
\end{array}
\right] \sim
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
7 & 7\\
2 & -30
\end{array}
\right] \sim
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 97\\
2 & -30
\end{array}
\right]
$$ and concluded that $97^{-1}=97$.

My question is how exactly does this method work and why didn't he row reduce traditionally into row echelon form?

Comment: This method really just solves the two simultaneous equations $97x = 1$ (true for some specific $x = 97^{-1}$) and $224x = 0$ (true for any $x$, so in particular for $x = 97^{-1}$) without using division. It ends up with $1x = 97$ (and $2x = -30$).

Comment: This looks like the [Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm).

Comment: So he ran the algorithm on the matrix?

Comment: It looks like the video does row reduction but stops when it gets 1 in the upper left entry --- no need to continue on to row echelon form, since you can read off the answer from what you get to.

Comment: @FrankEpps See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/252923/26306).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, this is a compact form of the [extended Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) (the typical way of finding modular inverses). I think the best way to see what is going on is to compare the matrix calculations to the calculations that you get coming out of the extended Euclidean algorithm.

If you get stuck, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/252923/9754) by Marc van Leeuwen explains what's happening.